# Can all $4a(1-b)$, $4b(1-c)$, $4c(1-d)$ and $4d(1-a)$ be greater than $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be arbitrary positive real numbers. Can all the products
$4a(1-b)$, $4b(1-c)$, $4c(1-d)$ and $4d(1-a)$ be greater than $1$?

Any idea how to solve this, because I don't know anything else except that $a,b,c,d>0$ and $4a(1-b)$, $4b(1-c)$, $4c(1-d)$, $4d(1-a)>1$, if and only if such numbers exist.

Comment: It seems like you might try applying AM/GM to $a,b,c,d,1-a,1-b,1-c,1-d.$

Comment: Just multiply all and see what happens when you regroup in $4a(1-a)$ etc

Comment: We've been learning about AM-GM inequalities, but which pair should I use them for, because I'll get the square root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let all these values be greater than $1$:

$$\begin{cases} 4a(1-b)>1\\4b(1-c)>1\\4c(1-d)>1\\4d(1-a)>1\end{cases}$$

Then their product is greater than $1$: $$4a(1-b)\times 4b(1-c)\times 4c(1-d)\times 4d(1-a)>1.$$

The square root of it is also greater than $1$: $$\sqrt{4a(1-b)\times 4b(1-c)\times 4c(1-d)\times 4d(1-a)}>1.$$

Reshuffle the factors a bit:

$$\sqrt{4a(1-a)}\times \sqrt{4b(1-b)}\times \sqrt{4c(1-c)}\times \sqrt{4d(1-d)}>1$$

$$2\sqrt{a(1-a)}\times 2\sqrt{b(1-b)}\times 2\sqrt{c(1-c)}\times 2\sqrt{d(1-d)}>1.\tag1$$

Note that $\sqrt{a(1-a)}$ exists, since $a(1-a)$ is always positive. Indeed, $a>0$ and $d(1-a)>0$, so $1-a>0$. The same with the other square roots.

Now, due to AM-GM we have:

$$\begin{cases} a+(1-a)\ge2\sqrt{a(1-a)}\\ b+(1-b)\ge2\sqrt{b(1-b)}\\ c+(1-c)\ge2\sqrt{c(1-c)}\\ d+(1-d)\ge2\sqrt{d(1-d)} \end{cases}$$

Or

$$\begin{cases} 1\ge2\sqrt{a(1-a)}\\ 1\ge2\sqrt{b(1-b)}\\ 1\ge2\sqrt{c(1-c)}\\ 1\ge2\sqrt{d(1-d)} \end{cases}$$

Multiplying those we get: $$1\ge 2\sqrt{a(1-a)}\times 2\sqrt{b(1-b)}\times 2\sqrt{c(1-c)}\times 2\sqrt{d(1-d)},$$

which contradicts $(1)$. Our assumption lead to the contradiction.

Comment: @CalvinLin (1) yes, a typo, thanks for letting me know. (2) We can because all $x$ and $1-x$ are positive, I write about that a little further.

Comment: @CalvinLin (3) It is written so in the OP’s question. The numbers are positive.

Answer (score 5):

For all of them to be greater than 1, the necessary condition is that their product must be greater than 1. By completing the square, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$
$$a(1-a)=-\left(a-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{1}{4}\le\dfrac{1}{4}$$
Therefore, for all $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4$, we have
\begin{align*}4a(1-b)\times4b(1-c)\times4c(1-d)\times4d(1-a)&=4^4a(1-a)b(1-b)c(1-c)d(1-d)\\&\le4^4\times\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^4\\&=1\end{align*}
Therefore, they cannot be all greater than $1$.

**Edit 1:** Thanks for Macavity for the clarification. We should first eliminate the case on $[1,+\infty)$ to ensure the inequality on the second last line is true (take care about the sign). But this is easy to eliminate as we need $$a(1-b)>0,b(1-c)>0,c(1-d)>0,d(1-a)>0\iff 1-a,1-b,1-c,1-d>0$$
So we have $0<a,b,c,d<1$.